# Swift: listen to url property then download photo

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I run this code in viewDidLoad, but Profile.currentProfile does not have the photoUrl yet, so it is nil and this code never runs

```
private func getProfilePicture() {
    if let photoURLString = Profile.currentProfile?.photoUrl {
        if let photoURL = URL(string: photoURLString) {
            if let photoData = try? Data(contentsOf: photoURL) {
                self.profilePhotoView.image = UIImage(data: photoData)
                self.letsGoButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.profilePhotoView.image = UIImage(named: "default-profile-icon")
    }
}
```

How can I wait until the photoUrl is not nil, then run this code? Thanks

Rik

(edit) this is how profile is set. This is called before the viewController is instantiated.

```
func copyProfileFieldsFromFB(completionHandler: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)) {
    guard AccessToken.current != nil else { return }
    let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                               parameters: ["fields": "email,first_name,last_name,gender, picture.width(480).height(480)"])
    request.start(completionHandler: { (_, result, error) in
        if let data = result as? [String: Any] {
            if let firstName = data["first_name"] {
                Profile.currentProfile?.firstName = firstName as? String
            }
            if let lastName = data["last_name"] {
                Profile.currentProfile?.lastName = lastName as? String
            }
            if let email = data["email"] {
                Profile.currentProfile?.email = email as? String
            }
            if let picture = data["picture"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let imageData = picture["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                    if let url = imageData["url"] as? String {
                        Profile.currentProfile?.photoUrl = url
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        completionHandler(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide additional context about how Profile is set?   Is Profile coming from an API call?

Comment: Yes, it is coming from Facebook @valosip (problem edited)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'll want to use completion handlers to keep track of asynchronous activities. So in your viewDidLoad() you could call something like

```
    Profile.currentProfile?.getPhotoURL { urlString in
        if let photoURL = URL(string: photoURLString) {
        if let photoData = try? Data(contentsOf: photoURL) {
            self.profilePhotoView.image = UIImage(data: photoData)
            self.letsGoButton.isEnabled = true
             }
         }
     }
```

And on your Profile class it would look something like this:

```
 func getPhotoURL(completion: @escaping (urlString) -> Void) {
     // get urlString
     completion(urlString)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add private var `profileUrl` and use didSet observing with it:

```
... //e.g. your controller
private var profileUrl: URL? {
    didSet {
        if let url = profileUrl {
            getProfilePicture(from: url)// update your func 
        }
    }
}
```